# CKEDITOR : How can I add extra item in rich combo box after instance ready

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I have a custom rich combo drop-down box named as `characterStyle`. When the CKEditor instance Ready the character style dropdown is loaded perfectly with all items.

```
editor.ui.addRichCombo( 'characterStyle',{
init : function(){
             charSetting = this;
              this.startGroup("Character Styles");
               for(var  i=0; i<styles.length;i++){
                   this.add(styles[i].name,styles[i].name,styles[i].element);
               }
            },
});
```

I have all items inside the **styles Array**

I want to add an item in character styles plugin after user create the new style (i.e after instance Ready).

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Can you elaborate more exactly what you want to acheive

Comment: Hi Nikhil, I want to add one more row. which means examples if we have font family combo box ok.  now I want to add one more font in the combo box in some button clicks after editor instance ready.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you to go to `CKEditor.js` of root and find following line

`CKEDITOR.config.font_names = "Arial/Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;` 
**Jokerman**
`;
Comic Sans MS/Comic Sans MS, cursive;Courier New/Courier New, Courier, monospace;Georgia/Georgia, serif;Lucida Sans Unicode/Lucida Sans Unicode, Lucida Grande, sans-serif;Tahoma/Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;Times New Roman/Times New Roman, Times, serif;Trebuchet MS/Trebuchet MS, Helvetica, sans-serif;Verdana/Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif";`

And Add 'Jokerman'

you can configure you font family name in there and check the result

[image]

Comment: How can I add those things in after instance Ready without using config.js file and get the row information form user(using textbox input)

Comment: You want to add it dynamically after instanceReady is called

Comment: is there any way to reinitialize the plugins after instanceReady?

Comment: You need to destroy the instance and replace it

Comment: try destroying $('.editor').on('focusout', function(){
   $(this).ckeditor(function(){
        this.destroy();
    });
}); and then again initialize

Comment: No, I can't do that because the whole content of the editor is vanished

Comment: yes it will thats why it is not possible or you can save the currunt content in some div andthen distroy and after reinitialisation put the content again

Comment: Ok, Thanks Nikhil

Comment: one more question is there any way to add search in a drop-down. whether input text box search or keypress event search?